# Using NSAttributedString with multiple foregroundColor makes the text in UILabel look lower than expected

Tags: uilabel, nsattributedstring, textkit

### Demo

https://github.com/NSFish/NSAttributedStringWithMultipleForegroundColor

### Description

Here I have a UILabel as simple as it could be

```
let label = UILabel()
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
label.numberOfLines = 2
view.addSubview(label)
// autolayout stuff..
```

And an NSAttributedString configured to meet the designer's intent

```
let content = " 自营  回力/WARRIOR 轮胎 215/65R16 98H SR1"
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: content)
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
let baselineOffset = (lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 4
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
                                                  NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                                                  NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset: Int(baselineOffset)]

attributedText.setAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.count))

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.count))

label.attributedText = attributedText
```

The content string showed up in the center of the UILabel, just as expected. But when I changed the first two chars' foregroundColor, things started to go wrong

```
// text looks lower
var prefixAttributes = attributes
prefixAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.white
attributedText.setAttributes(prefixAttributes, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: 5))
attributedText.setAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange.init(location: 5, length: content.count - 5))
// text in the center, works
// attributedText.setAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.count))
```

The only difference here is the foregroundColor at range(0, 5) changed to white.

### Result

[image: before]
[image: after]

### Question

I'm not very familiar with TextKit, but I do know the position of the text inside a UILabel is supposed to be decided by baselineOffset, or at least something, anything, but the foregroundColor of the text...

Comment: Could you print the `label.attributedText` in both cases? Not related, but be careful, `NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.count)`, use `content.utf16.count`, because its expects UTF16 so the `content.count` might differs.

Comment: @Larme the content variable already shows what you want, and NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.count) was used in both cases.